# REST request of different length

Tags: rest

When a client requests my `.../resources/user` URL with a `HTTP GET` I get the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<collection>
    <User id="5">
        <Password>DC647EB65E6711E155375218212B3964</Password>
        <FirstName>Super</FirstName>
        <LastName>Admin</LastName>
        <Role id="4">
            <Description>Default Guest Role</Description>
            <Group id="2">
                <Description>Default Guest Group</Description>
                <Name>GuestGroup</Name>
            </Group>
            <Name>Guest</Name>
        </Role>
        <Role id="3">
            <Description>Default Super Admin Role</Description>
            <Group id="1">
                <Description>Default Admin Group</Description>
                <Name>AdminGroup</Name>
            </Group>
            <Name>SuperAdmin</Name>
        </Role>
        <Username>superadmin</Username>
    </User>
    <User id="6">
        <Password>DC647EB65E6711E155375218212B3964</Password>
        <FirstName/>
        <LastName>Guest</LastName>
        <Role id="4">
            <Description>Default Guest Role</Description>
            <Group id="2">
                <Description>Default Guest Group</Description>
                <Name>GuestGroup</Name>
            </Group>
            <Name>Guest</Name>
        </Role>
        <Username>guest</Username>
    </User>
</collection>
```

For data transport efficiency purposes I would also like the client to be able to request a short version of this response. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<collection>
    <User id="5">
        <Password>DC647EB65E6711E155375218212B3964</Password>
        <FirstName>Super</FirstName>
        <LastName>Admin</LastName>
        <Role id="4" />
        <Role id="3" />
        <Username>superadmin</Username>
    </User>
    <User id="6">
        <Password>DC647EB65E6711E155375218212B3964</Password>
        <FirstName/>
        <LastName>Guest</LastName>
        <Role id="4" />
        <Username>guest</Username>
    </User>
</collection>
```

What is the best way to identify a full and a short request from the client and why? Client technology should be agnostic. Server technology is Java EE 7

A few options I thought of myself:

- Sub level webservices like `.../resources/user/short`
- Different webservices like `.../resources/user2`
- Use a custom HTTP parameter lik `Accept-Length : Short`
- Use the HTTP request field `Expect : Short`

Comment: Too opinion based for an answer, but I would probably go for a query parameter: `/resources/user?format=full`(default) or `/resources/user?format=short`. Or provide only the short format, with links for the embedded Role resources.

Comment: Query parameter sounds right. You could model it after JIRA's API, they call it [expansion](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#expansion). Honoring a JSON Content-Type header would shave some bytes off too.

Comment: I would avoid returning a password hash via API. Another potential issue is that your hash looks unsalted. Password hashes should be slow and salted.

Comment: Thanks @Hey for pointing me to the JIRA api solution. Perfect choice in my opinion.

Comment: @MartijnBurger no problem, this was actually one of my favorite features when consuming JIRA's APIs. Can save a *lot* of extra requests when you need to drill down on every member of a data set.

Comment: I would disagree with doing this with a query string. It makes more sense to do this with Content-Type. Make a content type for the long form and one for the short form and then let clients tell the server which they prefer to get via the Accept header. For example "Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.usershortform, application/vnd.mycompany.user"

Comment: Why does that make more sense?

Comment: Because the query strings are designed for filtering resources rather than specifying the format of the resource. Content-Type specifies the form to return the resource in. Saying I want it in short form is no different to saying I want it in JSON instead of default HTML or saying give me a picture in PNG rather than JPEG. It is a formatting issue which is what Content Type was designed for.

Comment: Have a look at the spec for the "Accept" header and for the HTTP status code "406" which deal with handling the format negotiation between the client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view is that the client is requesting a different representation of the resource i.e. a short one.

When you request a different representation (like json or xml) this normally gets tagged at the end of the resource e.g. `/some/resource.json, /some/resource.xml`

So you could take the same logic and do something like `/some/resource.short.json`

Comment: Great presentation about this subject ccan be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVvL12BnIyQ